HTTP certificate file authentication works fine with curl, with openssl, but not with Python module "requests"
I'm trying to make a post via "requests" in python, on a url where client certificate authentication is mandatory.
Certificates are production ones (not self signed)
Script is simple :
import requests 
print(requests.post('https://my_url.com', cert=('client.pem', 'key.pem'),data='<a>foo</a>', verify='ca.pem'))

I get the error :
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

Of course, it works fine when I set :
verify=False

With the same certificates (and key), it works fine with curl :
[ec2-user@ec2-instance ~]$ curl -w "%{http_code}\n" -s -o /dev/null -X POST https://my_url.com --cert client.pem --key key.pem --cacert ca.pem --data-binary "@some_file"
200

And I got no errors using openssl :
[ec2-user@ec2-instance ~]$ openssl s_client -connect my_url.com:443 -cert client.pem -key key.pem -CAfile ca.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = FR, O = ******, CN = ******
verify return:1
depth=1 C = FR, O = ******, OU = ******, organizationIdentifier = ******, CN = ******
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, L = ******, O = ******, CN = ******
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = FR, L = ******, O = ******, CN = ******
   i:C = FR, O = ******, OU = ******, organizationIdentifier = ******, CN = ******
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jun 12 22:00:00 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Jun 12 21:59:59 2025 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...blah...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = FR, L = ******, O = ******, CN = ******
issuer=C = FR, O = ******, OU = ******, organizationIdentifier = ******, CN = ******
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
...blah...
---
SSL handshake has read 3450 bytes and written 5346 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)

What am I missing here ?

You faced the ssl.SSLCertVerificationError indicates an issue with the SSL certificate verification, so firstly check your OpenSSL version in Python:
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

If that looks correct, try using a custom SSL context:
import requests
import ssl

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_verify_locations('ca.pem')
context.load_cert_chain(certfile='client.pem', keyfile='key.pem')

try:
    response = requests.post('https://my_url.com', data='<a>foo</a>', verify='ca.pem')
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print(f'SSL error: {e}')


openssl version matches in python and os (OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023), same error with SSLContext

your client.pem and ca.pem files are in the correct PEM format? both start by -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
also did u try to combine both of them and use it?
cat client.pem key.pem > combined.pem
in the code:
context.load_cert_chain(certfile='combined.pem')

yes they are in correct format, and no combine the client cert and its pkey doesn't work

without verifying it's work?
response = requests.post('https://my_url.com', data='<a>foo</a>', verify=False)

yes it works with verify=False as stated in the question

mmmm, do u try to verify the files using openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client.pem ?

this command is returning verified OK

as far as I understand, python isn't able to validate the server certificate

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Finally the matter is closed : on the server side (tomcat), there was missing the CA chain certificate in the keystore. But why no errors on curl and openssl remains a mystery to me !
